# 50 watt brick LED , JW19818 chip

Tags: led, constant-current

The JW19818 chip says 4 watt power.  There are 50 watt LEDs connected to 2 chips in this schematic. Can anyone explain?

[image: JW19818 50 watt led]

Comment: Where did you find 4 W specification for JW19818?  In the datasheet I could find, there is no such rating. https://v1.cecdn.yun300.cn/100001_2101295378%2FJW19818T_Datasheet_R0.12_EN_20200423.pdf

Comment: Are you confusing the power dissipation of the IC with the power dissipation of the LEDs it's driving?

Comment: 4 watts in data sheet @klas-kenny check https://en.publicxin.com/product/49.html

Comment: I am confused with IC power dissipation and led power. @brhans . Though I knew a little on power dissipation like voltage drop across the JW19818 and the current thru it , still I am confused . Similar chip in a mobile phone adaptor (high side converter chip) got burnt .

Comment: Yes, power dissipation of the JW is the voltage drop across it multiplied by the current thru it - and similarly the dissipation of the LED string is the voltage drop across the LED string multiplied by the current thru it. Since the JW is in series with the string those currents are the same, but the voltage drops are not. So it's entirely plausible for the JW to be dissipating 4W while the LEDs dissipate some other value like 50W.

Answer (score 1):

I still have not seen a *datasheet* with any 4 W specification, only a product listing which is quite common to be incorrect.
Anyway, I'll do some explanation;

The JW19818 is pretty much just a constant current driver. It does not really care about the LED power, only the current through the LED's.

In the schematic, there are two JW19818 in parallell, each set to 65 mA so the LED drive current will be twice that (since there are two in parallell), 130 mA.
Then, looking at [Some generic white 3528 LED](https://www.inolux-corp.com/datasheet/SMDLED/Mono%20Color%20Top%20View/IN-P23CTKG_V1.0.pdf) with a typical forward voltage of 3.4 V, each LED will produce `3.4x0.13 = 0.44 W`.

With 50 of these LED's, there's a total output power of about 22 W. That's not 50 W as specified, but as usual you should not really trust random schematics found online. It'll probably work, but not with 50 W of output.

Now, with 230 V typical input voltage and a total voltage drop of `50x3.4 = 170 V` over the LED's, this gives about 70 V of drop over the JW19818. So each JW19818 will need to dissipate about `60x0.065 = 3.9 W`.

This might be where the 4 W rating comes in, it might be (although unclear since it is not well specified) that the maximum allowed power dissipated by the JW19818 is 4 W, but that does not directly relate to the LED power. The power dissipation of the driver itself relates only to the combination of its drive current and voltage drop.

Comment: In another board , 50 green leds are connected in series after rectification for 230V operation . 2 driver chips are paralled . You forgot to take rectified voltage it's more than 230V (no smoothing caps used) @Klas-Kenny

Comment: @MayaMaya Without smoothing capacitors, rectified RMS voltage will still be 230 V. Only with smoothing, the RMS voltage will increase. Peak doesn't matter for average power dissipation that I considered in this post.